# how to select some words by using regular expression?

Tags: regex

Every result says `So, Basically, it's like a X for Y`, where `X` and `Y` are pulled from a database of ideas.

For example, I need to change or select `Flickr\tAlcoholics` part from

```
So, Basically, It's Like A Flickr for Alcoholics.
```

How do I select just `X` and `Y` part by using Regular expression?

Comment: What regex have you tried?

Comment: I think I need to use S.* to select "So," part but couldn't figure out how to select it before X..

Comment: Does `So, Basically, it's like a (.+?) for (.+)` work?

Comment: This also works `(?<=like\sa)(.*?)for(.*?)$`

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern `(?i)so, basically, it's like a (.+) for (.+)`.

Use flag `(?i)` to make the search case insensitive. Then capture `X` and `Y` part into capturing groups and replace it with `\1\t\2` to get desired result.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IWOv2I/1)